# Error when trying to open PowerPoint programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

I have a method that uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application interface to convert PowerPoint presentation slides into a jpeg files. In a service application that runs on Windows 2008 server it works without any issues.

Now however, I'm writing a new web application that uses the same process and the degubber chokes on the Presentation.Open call wiht an error: "PowerPoint could not open file".

My environment is Win 7, VS 2010. I'm using impersonation with a domain account that has admin privileges. The PowePoint file I'm trying to open is in the c:\temp folder which has NTFS rights of "everyone" set to full; file is NOT read-only, I can manually opent the file using a similar account as the domain account I'm using for impersonation. I don't know what the problem is. Can someone suggest what's going on?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using AjaxControlToolkit;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using System.Threading;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  private static int folderExtension;
  private static string tempSavePath,
                        fileName;

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Random r = new Random();
    int eventID = r.Next(1, 65535);
    Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    string err = "\nPage_Error Event" +
            "\n\nError in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
            "\n\nError Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
            "\n\nStack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString() +
            "\n";
    uploadResult.Text = err.ToString();        
  }

  protected void AsyncFileUpload1_click(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
  {
     // Temporary folder where the presentation file is uploaded.
     tempSavePath = @"c:\temp\";

     // Checks if there is a file present for uploading.
     if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
     {
        fileName = AsyncFileUpload1.FileName;

        try
        {
            AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(tempSavePath + fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            ConvertToJpegs();
        }
     }
     else
     {
        uploadResult.Text = "No file to upload.";
     }
 }

 // Converts the presentation slides into individual jpeg files.
 protected void ConvertToJpegs()
 {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState ofalse = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState otrue = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;

    Presentation pptPresentation = null;

    try
    {
     **>>> It break here with the ".Open" call <<<**   
        pptPresentation = app.Presentations.Open(tempSavePath + fileName, ofalse, ofalse, ofalse);
        pptPresentation.SaveAs(tempSavePath + ".", PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, ofalse);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        throw ex1;
    }
    finally
    {
        pptPresentation.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you are trying to achieve seems to be unsupported / not recommended by Microsoft:

> All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and
>   configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They
>   assume an interactive desktop and user profile. *They do not provide
>   the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the
>   needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.*
>
> Microsoft **does not currently recommend**, and **does not support**,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from *any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services)*, because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> *If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you
>   should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended
>   execution.* Or, you should try to **find alternatives that allow at least
>   part of the code to run client-side**. If you use an Office application
>   from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the
>   necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be
>   taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

With that said, it seems that a couple of other people have experienced a similar behavior under these settings, so I suggest you take a look at:

- [Powerpoint could not open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081540/powerpoint-could-not-open-file)
- [Powerpoint Interop fails in a Windows Service but works fine in a Windows Form application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729609/powerpoint-interop-fails-in-a-windows-service-but-works-fine-in-a-windows-form-a)
- [Automating Office via Windows Service on Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006923/automating-office-via-windows-service-on-server-2008)

And further, to check that you open the `.pptx` right, I just tried the PowerPoint Interop bits of your code sample in a C# .NET 4.5 console application using PowerPoint Interop v. 15 (for Office 2013) on a standard desktop PC. And that works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

How do you run you web app? Is it IIS 7.5 or Asp.Ne development Server?
If it's asp.net development server,  you should start it as administrator.
if that is IIS, i will need version of IIS.

Comment: You should use comments for question. Answer should be used when you have something useful for OP.