# Office.Interop.Powerpoint import

Tags: c#, interop, powerpoint

I am having trouble with PowerPoint conversion to HTML.

Here is code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application oApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation oPresentation = oApplication.Presentations.Open(sourceFileName);
oPresentation.SaveAs(destFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsHTML);
oPresentation.Close();
oApplication.Quit();
```

I get the following error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80048240):
>   Presentations (unknown member) : Invalid request. The PowerPoint Frame
>   window does not exist. at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations.Open(String
>   FileName, MsoTriState ReadOnly, MsoTriState Untitled, MsoTriState
>   WithWindow) at
>   SmartBoard_V2.Section.Admin.Areas.DersEditor.DersEdit.convertPowerPoint(String
>   fennKod) in c:\Users\Kamandar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\SmartBoard_V2\SmartBoard_V2\Section\Admin\Areas\DersEditor\DersEdit.aspx.cs:line 163

Comment: You should not use Office in an ASP.NET page. This is known source of problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you're automating PPT 2013 (or presumably later), this won't work.  As of 2013, PowerPoint no longer has a SaveAsHTML method.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you need to set the application to visible before you try and save it.

To do this simply add the following code before declaring the `oPresentation` object.

```
oApplication .Visible = Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

Edit: Just noticed you are using ASP.NET, Although it is not recommended, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425620/error-when-trying-to-open-powerpoint-programatically) for a similar problem.

Comment: You can't in ASP.NET. The w3wp is not user interactive.

Comment: Ah didn't see he was using ASP.NET, this would solve the problem otherwise.